# Hide Javascript if not applicable (ASP.NET MVC) tidy up

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How can I tidy this up?

```
@if(Condition==true)
{
   @:ptr++;
   @:if(ptr==10)
   @:  ptr=0;
}
```

I know it doesn't make much sense the code but whats the best so I don't have to keep putting @: on every line?  I don't want answer that says

```
@ptr++;if(ptr==10)ptr=0;
```

I want to know if there's another way so the code is formatted nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  tags

```
@if(Condition==true)
{
   <text>
   ptr++;
   if(ptr==10)
     ptr=0;
   </text>
}
```

ref: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax